# How to exclude categories from a sidebar with active widgets in it?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, widgets, sidebar

Is there a way to exclude certain categories from a widgetised sidebar? I've got categories that are associated with custom post types and ones associated with my blog - I don't want to display the CPT categories when viewing my blog.

Any ideas? All I can think of is that I have to hard code the sidebar instead and ditch the widgetised version.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, a quick solution could be using something like [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) and create a custom menu for each category, then use whatever [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) applies.// such as `is_category()` or `in_category( '5' )`  Or, if you don't want to use a plug-in, you could try duplicating the widget and then adding the conditional tag there... hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The categories in widget are retrieved in following way:

```
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

So you can make use of this filter to modify arguments.

However it might be simpler to use alternative widget, for example one from [Widgets Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-reloaded/), that offers more control via interface.

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin.
Where do I find this: wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));

Comment: @Evie Milo this is code from widget. You can hook into `widget_categories_args` to adjust the arguments, used to retrieve the categories in widget. See [Plugin API > Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) if you need info about hooks.